# The "contact us" link in the User Merge help page links to itself

Tags: bug, status-completed

It seems that https://askubuntu.com/contact/user-merge now redirects to https://askubuntu.com/help/merging-accounts (since a recent build of the site). Fine. However, the link on the page for further instructions links to itself.

> #### I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?
>
> If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please [contact us](https://askubuntu.com/help/user-merge) to do so. You will need links to the two profiles you would like to merge.

Clicking this "contact us" loads the same page, whereas one can expect it to link to another page for merging accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It now points to the contact page where a merge can be requested.